# Pandas drop_duplicates with multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, drop-duplicates

I have some measurement datas that need to be filtered, I read them as dataframe data, like these:

df

```
         RequestTime  RequestID  ResponseTime  ResponseID
0          150         14           103         101
1          150         15           110         102
2           25         16           121         103
3           25         16            97         104
4           22         16            44         105
5           19         17            44         106
6           26         18            29         106
7           30         18            29         106
```

and I need to use two different conditions at the same time, that is, to filter 'RequestTime' 'RequestID' and 'ResponseTime' 'ResponseID' by use drop_duplicate(subset=) at the same time. I have used follow command to get the filter results for each of the two conditions:

```
    >>>df[['RequestTime','RequestID','ResponseTime','ResponseID']].drop_duplicates(subset = ['ResponseTime','ResponseID'])

RequestTime  RequestID  ResponseTime  ResponseID
0          150         14           103         101
1          150         15           110         102
2           25         16           121         103
4           22         16            44         105
5           19         17            44         106
6           26         18            29         106
7           30         18            29         106
    >>>df[['RequestTime','RequestID','ResponseTime','ResponseID']].drop_duplicates(subset = ['RequestTime','RequestID'])

RequestTime  RequestID  ResponseTime  ResponseID
0          150         14           103         101
1          150         15           110         102
2           25         16           121         103
3           25         16            97         104
4           22         16            44         105
5           19         17            44         106
6           26         18            29         106
```

but how to combine the two conditions to drop duplicate row 3 and row 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
m = ~(df.duplicated(subset=['RequestTime','RequestID']) | df.duplicated(subset=['ResponseTime', 'ResponseID']))
df[m]
```

Output:

```
   RequestTime  RequestID  ResponseTime  ResponseID
0          150         14           103         101
1          150         15           110         102
2           25         16           121         103
4           22         16            44         105
5           19         17            44         106
6           26         18            29         106
```

Create a mask (boolean series) to boolean index your dataframe.

---

Or chain methods:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['RequestTime', 'RequestID']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ResponseTime', 'ResponseID'])
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your very quick reply. It’s the first time I came into this mask method. Very simple and useful. And chain methods also good.

Comment: Sorry I'm really newbie, just know how to accepting answer and done. Thank you.